# Turn off battery life warnings from Dell Feature Enhancement Pack

Tags: battery-life, dell-latitude

How to disable this annoying message that probably appears on any Dell laptop after about one year of usage (my personal experience from 3 different laptops)?

[image: Your battery is able to charge normally. However, you may begin to notice reduced operating time because your long-term battery life is decreasing.]

My Dell Feature Enhancement pack version is 2.2.1. There are some pieces of advice in the web, but they clearly don't fit this software version. It would be great not to have to remove this software completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The messages can be turned off with group policy administrative templates provided by DFEP. First you need to install them by copying the contents of `%PROGRAMFILES%\Dell\Feature Enhancement Pack\policydefinitions` to `%SYSTEMROOT%\PolicyDefinitions`. Then run `gpedit.msc`, navigate to `Local Computer Policy->Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates->System->Dell->Feature Enhancement Pack->System Events`, open the `Battery` policy, enable it and select the desired messages to disable.

Alternatively, you may use this reg file to disable the three battery health warning messages:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Dell\FeatureEnhancementPack\SystemEvent\Battery]
"BatteryCaution1"=dword:00000804
"BatteryCaution2"=dword:00000808
"BatteryReplace"=dword:00000810
```

Comment: Thank you! To clarify for users still searching for this, you only need the .admx files in the root of the policydefinitions folder along with the .adml files in the language folder of your default/current OS language.

For my laptop I was getting battery degraded messages on login, and I didn't want those each time, so I disabled the two options for "Battery health..." and then the option for "Battery requires replacement". Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I used a different method on my Dell Windows 7 laptop:

- Click on "Start"
- Then enter "msconfig".
- Click the "Startup" tab
- Then un-check the line(s) saying "Dell Feature Enhancement Pack".

Of course, this will keep the whole package from starting up.
But I don't seem to need it.

Comment: If you are going to prevent the tool from running, wouldn’t it be easier and safer (due to potential software vulnerabilities) to just uninstall the software?